# Client side vs server side logic

Tags: angular, web, client-side, server-side

I am trying to develop a website but I am confused about where to put my logic. 
Scenario: I want to update the list of items based on the filters selected by user. Example: [https://www.zillow.com](https://www.zillow.com/) . When user selects price range or home type etc, the list of houses gets updated.

So my question is should I make a network call everytime user selects a filter or pull all the items in the list and filter on the client side.
I am using Angular 4 for web development.

My concerns are:

- what if we have slower networks so the server side would not be that efficient.
- for mobile devices I don't think we should pull all the data in the device memory.

The items in the list would be in 1000s and item would be an object of 4 strings and 1 image.

Answer (score 1):

1000+ items are way too much for a single request, and the performance sure would be a problem for mobile devices. Do the filtering logic on the server and return only a small portion of the results (pagination). You would have more requests, but a slow network sure would have more problems with a gigantic initial request than one or more small ones.